# what is the best way to convert one dictionary to another

Tags: c#, linq, string, parsing, dictionary

i have one dictionary that has entries that looks like this:

```
dictionary["ABC.123"] = "Test"
dictionary["DEF.123"] = "Test2"
dictionary["EFG.123"] = "Test3"
dictionary["EFG.343"] = "Test3"
dictionary["ABC.456"] = "Test"
```

and i want to create a new dictionary that looks like this: (basically parse out the beginning string before the "." and create that as the key and use the same value.

```
dictionary["ABC"] = "Test"
dictionary["DEF"] = "Test2"
dictionary["EFG"] = "Test3"
```

as you can see: there is always a 1 to 1 mapping between the first part of the key in the first dictionary to the value so there will be no clashes

what is the easiest way using LINQ to convert to create the second dictionary from the first ??

I can loop through each record manually and parse out the new key and create each new record but i figured there was a LINQ way of doing it

Comment: @ooo: how did you do it?

Comment: @Mitch Wheat - by looping through each key in the dictionary and parsing out the new key and then setting the value to the new dictionary but i figured LINQ would have something more elegant . .

Comment: I meant "pleaese post your code" but nvm.

Comment: 4 lines with a loop, 1 line with LINQ (which runs the loop under the covers, possibly less efficiently).

Comment: @ooo: what do you expect to do with duplicate keys?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var newDict = dictionary.GroupBy(kvp => kvp.Key.Remove(kvp.Key.IndexOf('.')))
                        .ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, grp => grp.First().Value);
```

Although a plain `foreach` is probably going to be more readable and efficient:

```
var newDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (var kvp in dictionary)
{
    newDict[kvp.Key.Remove(kvp.Key.IndexOf('.'))] = kvp.Value;
}
```

Comment: +1 "Although a plain foreach is probably going to be more readable and efficient:" The intent is clearer.

Answer (score 6):

A simple approach is to use the Select method to generate your desired KeyValuePair in conjuntion with ToDictionary

```
var response = dictionary
              .Select(kvp => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(kvp.Key.Remove(kvp.Key.IndexOf('.')), kvp.Value))
              .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var dict2 = dictionary.GroupBy(x => x.Key.Split('.')[0])
                      .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.First().Value);
```